# Preventing submission after jQuery Validation Engine

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

Once clicking button, wanting to prevent submission to local storage if any required fields are not filled out. Both functions work properly. Just trying to prevent `LocalStorage.save()` from hitting if  `$("#formID").validationEngine();` finds a required field not completed.

```
<form id="formID" name="myForm">    

 <input class="validate[required]" type="text" id="agree" name="agree"/>         
 <button type="submit" value="Save" id="Save" onclick="clicked();">Submit Survey</button>

</form>

<script type="text/javascript">   
  function clicked() {
        if (confirm('Are you sure you want to submit?')) {

           $("#formID").validationEngine();               
           my.LocalStorage.save();

        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
 </script>
```

Comment: Does `validationEngine()` return a pass/fail boolean?

Comment: i believe so but not completely sure. https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine/blob/master/js/jquery.validationEngine.js

Comment: @Scott no, but `validationEngine('validate')` does

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From their documentation at http://posabsolute.github.io/jQuery-Validation-Engine/:

> ## validate
>
> Validates a form or field, displays error prompts accordingly. 
>   Returns *true* if the form validates, *false* if it contains errors.
>
> It is inversed for *fields*, it return false on validate and true on errors.
>
> When using form validation with ajax, it returns *undefined*, the
>   result is delivered asynchronously via function *options.onAjaxFormComplete*.
>
> ```
> // form validation 
> alert( $("#formID1").validationEngine('validate') );
>
> // field validation 
> alert( $("#emailInput").validationEngine('validate') );
> ```

So that would change your code to:

```
function clicked (e) 
{
    if ( confirm('Are you sure you want to submit?') ) 
       if ( $("#formID").validationEngine('validate') )
           my.LocalStorage.save();

    e.preventDefault();  
}
```

Take note that I added `e` as a parameter that needs `event` passed in via:

```
<button type="submit" value="Save" id="Save" onclick="clicked(event);">
    Submit Survey
</button>
```

Comment: neither function seems to be hitting. just reloads page after the js confirm

Comment: Maybe it's due to you not passing in `e` to the function and using `e.preventDefault()`.  I updated the code.  I think that should work. You'll have to update `onclick="clicked();"` to `onclick="clicked(e);"` I believe as well.

Comment: now its not even reaching the js confirms. without e in onclick= is same as before.

Comment: Try changing `onclick="clicked(e);"` to `onclick="clicked(event);`

Comment: Sweet ... sorry about that.  I had a brain fart since it's been so long since I've had to wireup events in markup after using jQuery for so long.  Lol!

Comment: I actually just realized it's not submitting .localstorage but everything else is as far as the if logic and validationEngine

Comment: If you `return true` instead of just `return`, does that allow the submission?

Comment: nope. for what its worth it does put agree="whatever text is put in" at the end of the URL. Wondering if the validationEngine is doing more with what is entered instead of just checking if text is there.

Comment: I see in their documentation `By default the engine use the form action to validate the form, you can however set a default url using: **ajaxFormValidationURL`.  So maybe you are right.  I'm not familiar with the plugin.  What I would do is set up `alerts` or `console.log` entries for each possible outcome and see where that leads you with their documentation.

Comment: Simply removed return and works fine. Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 3):

From [source code](https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine/blob/master/js/jquery.validationEngine.js#L104) there is a function `validate()` which returns true/false after validating

so use it

```
if( $("#formID1").validationEngine('validate'))
{
my.LocalStorage.save();
}
```

check this http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/jquery-form-validator-because-form-validation-is-a-mess/